# How to get pagination links using ajax (laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4, laravel-pagination

Good day,

How can I pass `e.g: $transactions->links();` when doing an ajax call on laravel?

Heres my Controller on a normal request:

```
$transactions = DB::table('x_general_transactions')
    ->whereBetween('x_general_transactions.date_at', array($startDate,$endDate))
    ->paginate(30);
```

VIEW

```
{{ $transactions->(array('from' => $startDate, 'to'=>$endDate))->links() }}
```

and on ajax request

```
if (Request::ajax())
    {
        //$divs is my data container
        $res = [$divs,$transactions->links()];
        return Response::json($res);
    }
```

so when I tried to use `.load` on my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
          url: href,
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
            $('.pagination').load(response[1]);
         });
 });
```

But nothing happens, I also tried

```
console.log(response[1]);
```

ajax response:

```
[[[{"gt_xid":1230,"gts_xid":1231,"xid":4728,"rnr":4,"code":"OR#","link_code":"CI#","link_rnr":6,"g_type":25,"account_name":"Cash on Hand","debit":50.5,"credit":0,"description":"","date_at":"2015-10-25 16:25:19"},{"gt_xid":1230,"gts_xid":1231,"xid":4729,"rnr":4,"code":"OR#","link_code":"CI#","link_rnr":6,"g_type":25,"account_name":"Accounts Receivable - Trade","debit":0,"credit":50.5,"description":"","date_at":"2015-10-25 16:25:19"}]],{}]
```

`result:`object {}` which is empty.

Comment: Can you post the JSON Response of the AJAX

Comment: thanks for passing by sir, I hav updated the question above.

Comment: you can check this https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902

Comment: as I understand his method loads a whole blade template right?  isnt there a way to load just the paginator because if its the case I have to re-code most of my views to apply this, where for now its the paginator links are the only ones one working properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

### Controller Response(use render to render html and send response)

```
if (Request::ajax())
{
 $res = array(
  'data' => $divs,
  'links' => $transactions->links()->render()
 );
 return Response::json($res);
}
```

### ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
          url: href,
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
             console.log(response.data);//get data
             console.log(response.links);//get links
            $('.pagination').load(response.data);
         });
 });
```

Comment: thank you for answering sir, but with this code I am still getting `object {}` as result of `console.log(response.links)`

Comment: helloo.. my bad.. i have edited answer please check.

Comment: I am very sorry to reply very late.. I had some errands to make.. but your answer is the best! I have been researching since yesterday and I had no idea that I could used render! xD then I was forced to apply this gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902 method that made me change most of my codes.. T.T anyways thank you very much your the best.. how I wished you had answered it yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help you

## Route:

```
Route::get('/home/ajax/get','TestController@getAjax');
```

## Controller :

```
public function getAjax() {

$transactions = DB::table('x_general_transactions')
    ->whereBetween('x_general_transactions.date_at', array($startDate,$endDate))
    ->paginate(30);
return View::make('home.ajax.data')->with('transaction',$transaction);
}
```

## View (home.ajax.data) :

Create php file for load data from TestController

```
<div id="content"> 
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>id</td>
   <td>transaction</td>
   <td>customer</td>
  </tr>
  @foreach($transaction as $key => $val )
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $val->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $val->transaction }}</td>
   <td>{{ $val->customer }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3" align="center">{{ $transaction->links() }}</td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 </table
</div>
```

## View (home) :

Home view load your page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Transaction</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
   @include('home.ajax.data')
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

## JS Script (home) :

Place this javascript on home view

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
    page = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
});
$(document).on('click','.pagination a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //to get what page, when you click paging
    var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
    //console.log(page);

    getTransaction(page);
    location.hash = page;
});
function getTransaction(page) {

    //console.log('getting sort for page = '+page);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '{{URL::to("/home/ajax/get?page=")}}'+page
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
}
```

REF : https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902